# Installing packages from source for all users

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, catkin-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to deploy a custom package and am having trouble getting it to work for all users on the machine.  Currently I have my targets installable using CMake's `install()` and things are working fine for a single user (i.e., I install to some install space and then source the resulting setup.bash file).

My problem is when I try to move my install space somewhere for all users to access.  Currently I am trying something to the effect of `/usr/local/ros/kinetic/`.  If I set my install space as such I get write permission errors; `catkin build` with sudo seems wrong (environment setup issues); and installing locally and then copying/moving the resulting folder results in  sourcing the resulting `setup.bash` having no effect.

I am using catkin-tools on Kinetic.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated at this point.

-Brett

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289660/installing-packages-from-source-for-all-users/) by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 525 on 2018-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're having trouble with write permissions using sudo. I'd recommend changing the permissions temporarily for the install destination to allow user write permissions. And then turn that off again after you've completed the installation.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-26**:
This is indeed an acceptable work-around.

@BrettHemes: I've used either `sudo -E catkin_make install` in the past (as `catkin_make` separates install phase from configure & build), or `sudo -E catkin build ..` as that should keep env vars around.

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2018-04-26**:
"-E
The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables."

Nice!, I will try this out.  Thanks!